# Mocking protected member of a class with constructor that has default argument values

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, moq

I know testing non public members is considered bad, but still why this doesn't work? 
It throws `ArgumentException` with message: Member `Connect` doesn't exists

```
public class FtpHelper : IFtpHelper
{
   public FtpHelper(ISignalRLogger signalRLogger, IDirectoryWrap directoryWrap = null) {
    ... some code
   }

   protected virtual IFtpClient Connect(string ftpPath) {
     ... some code
   }
}

public class TestFtpHelper
{
   [Fact]
   public void Calls_connect(){

      var signalrMq = new Mock<ISignalRLogger>();
      var clientMq = new Mock<FtpHelper>(
            MockBehavior.Strict, new { signalRLogger = signalrMq.Object });

      clientMq.Protected().Setup<IFtpClient>("Connect",new { ftpPath = ""})
    .Returns(It.IsAny<IFtpClient>()); // That doesn't work

   }
}
```

UPD: oh I noticed that even before the last line when it's initializing `clientMq` and I try to use `clientMq.Object` it throws Exception with this message: A matching constructor for the given arguments was not found on the mocked type. I guess it has something to do with that strange constructor with default value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what's wrong...
this:

```
var clientMq = new Mock<FtpHelper>(
            MockBehavior.Strict, new { signalRLogger = signalrMq.Object });
```

should be:

```
var clientMq = new Mock<FtpHelper>(
            MockBehavior.Strict, signalrMq.Object);
```

signature is `params object[]`

but now it throws `NullReferenceException`

Upd: the members that you're trying to mock not only should be `virtual` but also `internal'. Making them 'protected` simply not enough. Proxies can't be identified through `Refection.Emit()` and Moq uses that/

Answer (score 4):

You need following addtional setup
1. Add `using Moq.Protected()` at the top
2. Make types visible to Moq using `InternalsVisibleTo` attribute. 
    [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(RhinoMocks.NormalName)] 
    [assembly: InternalsVisibleTo(RhinoMocks.StrongName)]

From the [link](http://geekswithblogs.net/MattRobertsBlog/archive/2008/12/16/how-to-make-a-quotprotectedquot-method-available-for-quotpartialquot-mocking-and-again.aspx)

Comment: 1) using `Moq.Protected` is in the place 
2) they're in the same assembly

Comment: +1; note that you shouldn't need InternalsVisibleTo for protected methods. Also I'm not sure where the RhinoMocks reference comes in...